# Can't count() a PostgreSql table

Tags: postgresql

I have a moderately large PostgreSql table (~20M rows) with one index, receiving a small amount of traffic (1-2 inserts/sec).  When I try:

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM MyTable
```

The query never returns.  With an index on the table, shouldn't it be fulfillable from stats?

What could be the problem, and/or how can I diagnose what's going on?  Am running 9.6.15.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.6 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: It certainly feels like Postgres is doing the actual count query.  Check the duplicate link for some good workarounds.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: it doesn't "feel" like it. The query requires to scan the entire table to get an accurate count. An index won't really help there. But counting 20 million rows should only take a few seconds at most on modern hardware.

Comment: I would *at least* add a semicolon to the query.

Comment: "shouldn't it be fulfillable from stats"   No, count means "count", not "guess".  You can derive an estimate from the stats if you want, but count won't do that for you (other than as part of the planning)

Comment: Thanks for the help, all.  Using the estimation method, I got a reasonable count.  Still unsure why it refuses to finish a count, no matter how long I give it.    Oh, and to whomever marked this a duplicate question -- it isn't.  The question wasn't how to estimate the # of rows, but rather how to diagnose why the count wouldn't complete.